# Psionic Sorcerer: Psychic Strike with ongoing spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, unearthed-arcana

https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020_PsionicOptions.pdf

> Psychic Strike
> 6th-level Psionic Soul feature
> You have learned to channel additional psychic
> energy into your spells. Immediately after you
> deal damage to a creature with a sorcerer spell
> for which you expend a spell slot, you can roll
> your Psionic Talent die and also deal psychic
> damage to that creature equal to the number
> rolled. You can deal this extra damage only once
> per turn.

Does this work with an ongoing spell like witchbolt? Or something like Fire Shield?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### This works for ongoing spells.

The Psychic Strike ability has 2 conditions that must be satisfied:

- you deal damage with a sorcerer spell
- that spell expended a spell slot

So *any time* you deal damage with *any sorcerer spell of 1st level higher that you cast by expending a spell slot*, you meet the conditions for using Psychic Strike (as long as you haven't already used Psychic Strike this turn).

Comment: Sweet! So you can continue to deal bonus damage multiple times (over multiple turns). Very cool!

Comment: @EagerToLearn Is my answer good enough for a green check?

Comment: @EagerToLearn I would expect that loophole to be closed in the eventual published version of this (if one eventually happens), since that would tend to overpower damage-over-time spells.

Comment: Yup, thanks Thomas!